# How to request App Ratings with requestReview() correctly

Tags: swift, xcode, skstorereviewcontroller

I am currently learning how to ask the user for an AppStore rating in the app. I have read through numerous documentations and reports from Apple and other bloggers, but I still have questions:

1. I thought that I want to display my request after the user has completed a sequence of actions 3 times. But if the user doesn't want to rate my app right now, can I ask him to rate my app again later? I also read that Apple controls when and how often the review request is displayed (up to 3x / year)
2. My app has different functions. Therefore it is not guaranteed that the user accesses exactly this function, where I want to show the rating view. Is it therefore possible to call up the rating request at different points in the app and simply leave it up to Apple whether the rating request is also displayed?

Best regards

**Edit for @K bakalov :**

```
enum AppReviewRequest {
    
    @AppStorage("runCountSinceLastRequest") static var runCountSinceLastRequest = 0
    @AppStorage("lastVersion") static var lastVersion = ""
    
    static let threshold = 4
    static let currentVersion = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleVersion") as! String

    static func countUpRequestReview() {
        if currentVersion != lastVersion {
            if runCountSinceLastRequest < threshold - 1 {
                runCountSinceLastRequest += 1
                print(runCountSinceLastRequest)
            }
        }
    }
    
    static func requestReviewIfNeeded() {
        if currentVersion != lastVersion {
            if runCountSinceLastRequest == threshold {
                if let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first(where: { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }) as? UIWindowScene {
                    SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: scene)
                    
                    lastVersion = currentVersion
                    runCountSinceLastRequest = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you already read that but if you haven't I am leaving a link for you to check it out: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/requesting_app_store_reviews

It contains helpful information and guides when and how to prompt the user to leave a review.

Back to your questions.

1. - Yes, you can ask again for review but there is no guarantee that the Review pop-up (alert) will be presented again. It is usually delayed in time and sometimes requires a new update of the app to trigger a new review prompt; That is correct, Apple has control over it but I don't know if its limited to only 3 times a year.
2. - Yes, you can call it as many times as you want and wherever you find it suitable. Although, I highly encourage you to read (if still haven't) the link above. You need to think of a non-intrusive way to ask for review, otherwise you risk the user to dismiss the prompt, even if they like the app.

Just an advice, many apps use an approach with a custom popup "Do you like the app? Yes/No", if "Yes" then request a review using `requestReview()` call. And/or as mentioned in the article above, you can always use a manual review by redirecting to the AppStore, if you need it as a result of a CTA (tap on a button for example).

Comment: Thank you really much for your answer! Yes, I have already read this documentation. Regarding your suggestion about a query whether the user likes the app or not, I have already heard many opinions that said that this principle is also very unprofessional and that it is better to avoid it because, according to the Apple documentation, you should not use the request view as an action of a button. In that case, its a better pattern to deeplink the user to the appstore

Comment: Hey @k Bakalov, I had some more questions while programming, namely I built a function that only calls the .requestReview() method after a user defaults count is over or equal to 4. After that, the built number is also saved and only when there is a new built number can the requestReview() method be called again. I found this method on many platforms. But if it is not guaranteed that this requestReview() will be called because of Apple, then I have a big problem because the requestReview() will only be called again if the built number is changed. Do you understand my problem? Greetings!

Comment: My code ist in my question

Comment: My second and final question is that if the Request Review is called more than 1 time in the code, but the user has already given a review on the 1st request review, then this 2nd (or 3rd) request review will still be shown? Or will it only be called up a second or third time if the user hasn't rated it the first time?